# How to set urls properly in Salesforce site?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, force.com

In my Visualforce pages I have several links to another Visualforce pages
in developer edition I used hard coded links such like this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/apex/gindex" id="theLink">Back to shop</apex:outputLink>
```

On controller side

```
Public PageReference backToPage(){
    return new PageReference('/apex/gindex');
}
```

How to set them properly in force.com site?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use relative URL instead of absolute in apex:outputLink value like you do it in your controller:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/gindex" id="theLink">Back to shop</apex:outputLink>
```